# is there a way to configure ibm business automation with postgre sql?

Tags: postgresql, websphere, ibm-bpm

I have IBM Business Automation workflow 8.6.1.19002 installed and now i want to change my dbms which is oracle, but we want to use some opensource dbms for example postgre sql, so is there a way to do so. As per IBM's knowledge center it only supports oracle, sql server and db2. still I am looking for if any option is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All supported databases are listed here: [IBM Business Automation Workflow Detailed System Requirements](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=AF5A34D0561411E982882C5D069DA07A#sw-4)

There is no point of using other database, first because it is not supported and your installation will be not supported, second in the BAW license DB2 is included and you can install it without additional costs. So if you no longer want to use Oracle, then use provided DB2.